# Problem with draw2d dependency in Eclipse with zest

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-gef, zest

When trying to run [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF_Zest_Visualization) zest tutorial, I get the following error:

> The type
>   org.eclipse.draw2d.FigureCanvas cannot
>   be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class files

over the following bit of code:

```
GraphNode n = new GraphNode(g, SWT.NONE, "Paper");
```

I have gef 3.6.2 installed, so I don't get what may be the problem. All that Eclipse seems able to do is ask me if I want to configura my build path settings:

[image]

What may I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your project's manifest file and add dependency on org.eclipse.draw2d bundle.

Edit: What made it work was adding a couple of draw2d "external jars" to the project's dependencies. Thanks by the clue!

Comment: I am not very acknowledgeable of Eclipse's features. How would I go about finding the manifest file?

Comment: Your resolution sounds wrong... The manifest is located at META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. Open this file and you will see an editor with many pages. Open dependencies page and add dependency on the draw2d bundle.